# ScheduledNotification Inheritance

Tags: c#, silverlight, inheritance, constructor, windows-phone

I'm making a windows phone app using silverlight.

I want to make a class that inherit the ScheduledNotification built in class, but when I do this and start defining the constructor an error shows up saying: "The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledAction' has no constructors defined".

```
public class MyClass : ScheduledNotification 
{

    public MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

So how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScheduledAction has no parameterless constructor defined. Therefore, when constructing a class that inherits from it, you have to manually call one of the constructors :

```
public class MyClass : ScheduledNotification 
{

    public MyClass()
        : base("whatever") // Calling the parent's constructor
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is: neither the ScheduledNotification or the ScheduledAction have a public constructor (they are all marked as internal). So it's impossible for you to build a class that inherits from them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I can't, then how the classes  Reminder and Alarm are inherited from them??

Comment: Reminder and Alarm are internal classes. As such, they can call the internal constructors. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7c5ka91b(v=vs.80).aspx